# поиск по std::map и выдача значения по умолчанию

Tags: c++, c++11, map, find, default

есть `std::map<std::string, int>`

требуется найти значение по ключу или получить значение по умолчанию

подскажите, есть ли какая-то специализированная функция/метод или надо писать

```
const int value = (data.find(key) == data.cend()) ? default : data[key];
```

просто уж очень длинными и сложновоспринимаемыми записи оказываются, ищу способ сократить без ввода своей функции

Comment: Такое не годится?

`int value = data[key];`

Правда, если ключа такого нет - будет создан элемент с нулевым значением...

Comment: Так писать не надо, потому что поиск выполняется два раза. Так что пишите свою функцию с нормальным if. *"просто уж очень длинными и сложновоспринимаемыми записи оказываются"* - из приведенного примера не ясно, о чем речь.

Comment: @Harry, но тогда придется проверять на нулевое значение, а если элемент есть и в нем нулевое значение - т.е. такой подход некорректен

Comment: @user7860670, ну операция не является критичной по времени, поэтому и двойной поиск был бы терпимым (хотя конечно найти один раз и потом извлечь по итературу быстрее и правильнее). Касательно того, что не понятна суть - контейнер является глубоко вложенным и поэтому очень длинные конструкции `a.b.c.find()`, конечно и это "лечится", но опять же дополнительным кодом или использованием своей функции. Поэтому и интересен вопрос - есть ли встроенная функция/метод - все таки операция не такая уж и редкая, как мне кажется

Comment: ¿Где это видано, чтобы в С++ из коробки было что-то удобное? Готовых функций нету, делайте свою.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333728/stdmap-default-value